# adding exception to a larger block of code

Tags: sql-server, exception

How would I go about adding this exception to a larger block of code? I already have the first part where "all courses with students enrolled where GRADE_LEVEL = PK through 12"

```
select [...], [...], [...], 
case when [...] 
into #table
from #other
where grade in ('PK', 'KG', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')
and year = 2013
;
```

but then I have to do this:

Select all courses with students enrolled where GRADE_LEVEL = PK through 12 with the following exception:
When SURVEY = 2 and DISTRICT_INST = 1 through 75, select all course enrollments – except if SCHOOL_INST = 7001, 7004, 7023, 7006; or DISTRICT = 71; or CHARTER_SCHL_STAT < > ‘Z’ and SCHL_FUNC_SETTING = ‘V’; or STUDENT_LOCATION = ‘T’, then only select courses where COURSE_GRADE = ‘IP’

```
   select count(*) from #students a
   where a.district_inst between 1 and 75
   and a.school_inst not in (7001, 7004, 7023, 7006)
   or a.district = 71
   or a.charter_schl_stat <> 'Z' and a.schl_func_setting = 'V'
   or a.student_location = 'T'
   and a.COURSE_GRADE_STAT = 'IP'

Is there a way to use except if?
```

Comment: `if A then B` <=> `A implies B` <=> `(not A) or B`. [Also](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXCEPT is a keyword in SQL Server, but it doesn't work the way you would need it to, instead it's basically to compare two result sets, the opposite of INTERSECT.

For this you can get by with simple logic and brackets.

Your logic can be expressed like this:

Set 1 = all courses where the grade level is PK to 12 (as your original sample).

Set 2 = these are exceptions to the rule above, but I am assuming that these add to the results?  If not then the logic in my sample script will need changing.

Set 3 = these are exceptions to the exception, so items that would be allowed through the set 2 test, but then be excluded based on more complex logic.

Set 1 is simple, this is just anyone with the specified grade level.

Set 2 is also simple (if my understanding is correct), this is simply an exception to the constraint for set 1, based on the [survey] and [district_inst].  By bringing back all course enrolments we are basically saying that if any student passes the test for set 2 then SELECT all data for them.

Set 3 is an exception to set 2, where we bring back a constraint that the course grade must be "IP", but only for a subset of the data.

Putting this together, the logic is:

- either the row falls under set 1, in which case we include it;
- or it falls in set 2, but not set 3, in which case we include it;
- or it falls in set 2, and also in set 3, but has a course grade of "IP" so is included.

All other data is excluded.

I put together this, it might be wrong, but I have no way to test (no data):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    #students s
WHERE 
    --Grade level PK to 12
    s.grade_level IN ('PK', 'KG', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12')
    --Exception
    OR (
        s.survey = 2 
        AND s.district_inst BETWEEN 1 AND 75
        AND (NOT (
            s.school_inst IN (7001, 7004, 7023, 7006)
            OR s.district = 71
            OR (s.charter_schl_stat != 'Z' AND s.schl_func_setting = 'V')
            OR (s.student_location = 'T'))
        OR s.course_grade = 'IP'));
```

I imagine you will need to do some tweaking to this to get it to work exactly the way you want it.  Also, formatting SQL with multiple nested AND/ ORs with brackets becomes nasty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for how well you expressed the way you understood the logic! Definitely helped me understand it better myself! The code worked great too :)